# ASP.NET MVC Entities, DTO, Business objects, ViewModels? How do i manage this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I'm very busy with the architecture of a new MVC application, but i'm getting very confused about how to manage different type of objects. The confusion is about the relation between entities, business objects and viewmodels.
I 'm going to describe my confusion with an example:

I've set up my web application with different projects: MVC frontend, BLL, DAL, Common things etc.

Let's say i have a view with a List of bikes. I want to display the bike details like color, size, manufacturer. But in my database, the Bike and Manufacturer are two different tables, so in my Entity Framework context, these are also two different classes.

So i have these two entities Bike and Manufacturer. But in my business needs, i think they need to be a single object, which i can manipulate or use in business logic. Then there is my view, which needs a (View)Model. That should also be a combined ViewModel with properties from different tables.

How do i handle this? Do i need to get the Bike and Manufacturer object from my DAL, and create a business object from it in my BLL, and after doing some business logic, should i create a ViewModel from it in my controller? Or does my DAL need to return a combined business object? Or can i use the entity object as business classes? Or can i also use my business object as a ViewModel?

I hope that my problem is clear and that anyone can give me a good advise about which object are needed and how, where and when the different types of objects are created, and in which layer this classes should go...

Comment: Have a read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: @AmateurProgrammer thank you, this clears out at least the ViewModel part of my confusion. I see i can do mapping from Business Objects to ViewModel in my controller. But what about the relation between business objects and entities. Are they the same classes??

Comment: If by 'entities', you mean EF entities, then no. Your business entities are fundamentally logically different than your database/ORM entities. You are not going to apply your business logic directly on objects you get from the database. You would preferably map them to your business objects first. So basically an extra layer would come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is easy.  There is *NO* relationship between your different layers of models.  They are completely isolated, and do not refer to each other.  Not at all.  As such, there is nothing to be confused about.

You have code in different parts of your layer that maps between two layers UI->Business and Business->Data, but that should be the extent of any interaction between them.

Comment: Thank you Erik. Still there is some confusion as many tutorials are extracting the enity classes generated by Entity Framework to a seperate project/dll, which is referenced by all layers. So the DAL returns them, the BLL knows and receives them, and the UI layer views are rendering them. Is this generally a bad approach??

Comment: @Jeroen1984 - I believe tutorials tend to do that to simplify the scenario and avoid clouding their point. It is generally not advisable to do that for a number of reasons; it's harder to maintain and extend, raises security concerns (binding POST data directly to business entities) and introduces unnecessary coupling.

Comment: Remember that your view models and business entities are *different things* - the view model models the data for your view, which doesn't necessarily have a one-to-one mapping with the business model.

Comment: @AntP Thanks for sharing your thoughts with me. I think i'm starting to understand the concepts of how to handle this.

Comment: @Jeroen1984 - If your view, business, and data models are all the same, and your project is of sufficient enough simplicity (such as is the case in a tutorial), then that makes sense.  You have already disqualified that approach, however, by stating that your different layers model your data differently.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I understand, but who's ever writing such a straight forward application where view, business, and data models are all the same.

Comment: @Jeroen1984 - Tutorial writers ;)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch lol, in other words they are writing tutorials only suitable for other tutorial writers... Without kidding, most of the tutorials are very helpfull, but translating them to your own real world situation is sometimes not that easy...

Comment: @Jeroen1984 - It's an unfortunate reality that Tutorials often teach bad programming habits in the name of trying to clarify the subject they are teaching.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom business entities, that will be referenced in your views.

In you business implementation you can have some mapper that will map your Entity Framework entities to your custom business entities, you can use
[Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to achieve this.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you mean that translation your EF entities to custom business entities is a good approach? Where do i create this custom Business Entities? Should my DAL return them, or should i create them in my Business Layer?

Comment: So ideally it should be in your business layers, we're having it like "Business.Entities".

Comment: Ok, so the classes in Business.Entities are not your data entities (assuming you use some ORM like EF or NHibernate)? And you also do not use them as ViewModels?

Comment: So how we are doing in our project is,our custom business entities will be  in your business layers, we're having it like "Business.Entities", and our Business implementation will have a reference of Business.Entities and EF.Entities, and your PL will have a reference of just Business.Entities.

This is how generally we are doing in our most of the projects.

Comment: Check bellow ans with code, let me know if you have any confusion.
Please mark it as answer if it is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should have some common functionality where you'll have all your mapping for your Business and EF entities.

and in your implementation you will map just ask your mapper to provide actual entities.

There should be some common class that will create mappings for you.

Something like this

`public static void CreateTestMapping()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccess.Entities.Test, Business.Entities>()
                  .ForMember(s => s.Col1, d => d.MapFrom(t => t.Colabc))
                  .ForMember(s => s.Col2, d => d.MapFrom(t => t.ReferenceTable.RefTableCol1));
        }`

and in your business implementation you'll use this mapping to convert Business.Entities to EF.Entities and visa-versa

`Mapper.Map<Business.Entities.Test, EF.Entities.Test>(source, destination);`

Comment: And do i also need to implement this for the translation between my Business objects and ViewModels?

Comment: No, your business entities will act as your ViewModels.
As I mentioned above, your Business.Entities will be referenced in your PresentationLayer, so you can access your business.Entities in your views.

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is:

Your DAL returns a `List<Bike>` and a `List<Manufacturer>`.

Then your Business Layer should manipulate these and return to asp.net MVC an appropriate object.

For example a `List<Manufacturer>` which contains for every item a `List<Bike>`.

Create the appropriate ViewModels and add Controller logic to manipulate them BUT DO NOT do any core business manipulation there, just UI manipulation to suit your views.

Also i would recommend NOT to bind your UI with your DAL.

Keep your UI project referenceing the common libraries + Business layer project.

Let the business communicate with the DAL.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, part of confusion comes from the fact that you "can't" break all links between your projects even if you want for "design" and separation of concern reasons.

Well, in fact you can (and may be should) break, but the cost is, at least: lost intelisense and/or marshalling coding.

At the end, your projects are linked at least by a convention. One project expects a behavior from the other. If you publish weather data, you expect your DAL to provide weather data and not financial data, even if it should be wise to handle the case.

At least one project must expose an interface/DTO, and the other must implement this interface.

Usually and humbly, I try to make the business logic independent : business can be built without reference to any other project (PLEASE: note I speak of project not of layer). So My abstract classes or interfaces are in the business or domain project. Why: the most probable changes are GUI technology changing or persistence technology changing, so if you want to interact with me here are the contracts (false friend here).

So the web site (or any GUI) project references the business project and the DAL project, the DAL project references the business project.

- The controller get the data from the DAL and provide it to the domain/business logic
- The controller then provide the *unattached* result to razor, and/or persist the result by the DAL.

BUT imho, evil starts when you stop mastering the scope of your context (DbContext, ObjectContext,...). Other saying try to avoid providing attached object to Razor.